# How can I 'reset' the inertial scrolling in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, macos

Chrome 17 on Lion has inertial scrolling like Safari 5 does. However, sometimes it reaches a point where the top/bottom **edges are not bouncy anymore**. This happens on a user profile in Chrome without any installed extensions.

The inertial scrolling is still there, but without the bouncy edges. The latter can be restored by restarting the computer. Just restarting Chrome does not fix it.

- Is it possible to restore the bouncy scrolling in Chrome without restarting the computer?

---

I've issued at bug report at code.google.com.

#### [Issue 120188
The inertial scrolling is not bouncy at the top/bottom edges after some use](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=120188)

---

I've made two screen recordings:

1. [Scrolling OK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM_9e4_rb5w&feature=youtu.be)
2. [Scrolling BROKEN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KIYpKrUanA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I never noticed this before (it doesn’t bother me personally), but FWIW, Chrome 19.0.1081.0 canary still has this issue. Did you report a bug at http://new.crbug.com/? You should, if you want the Chrome engineeers to fix this.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Not yet, but I guess I'll do this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been removed with the latest Chrome update (18.0.1025.142).

You can read more about the update here:

- [Stable Channel Release 18.0.1025.142](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.de/2012/03/stable-channel-release-and-beta-channel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to top and bottom bouncy or left and right bouncy?

If left and right, it's because Chrome uses two-finger scrolling for back and forward before allowing bouncy. (I.e., if you can go back to a previous page but not forward, you can bounce on the right side but not the left. If you can't go back or forward, you can bounce on both sides. If you can go back and forward, you can't bounce on either side.) If you have two-finger back and forward gestures off (as I do), you still can't bounce laterally (which is very annoying, as I like to idly bounce the webpages as I read them).

Comment: I'm referring to the top/bottom bouncy behaviour.

Comment: @gentmatt I've not seen that behaviour, so I can't speculate as to why it happens. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure? Upon a fresh start, the bouncy behavior is the same in Chrome and Safari. Does Safari bounce at the top like Chrome does, or is it more gluey?

Comment: I don't see any difference. I've just never seen Chrome stop bouncing at the top and bottom. (Doesn't mean it doesn't happen, just that I've not seen it. I don't do much vertical bouncy on the desktop.)